# Admob causing app to load, but not show

Tags: android, admob

When admob is present in my app, the main layout (at times) will not display at all. Other times it starts just fine. I have had this intermittent issue for awhile now and cant figure out a way around it. Im sure it has something with the fetching of the ads (or the lack there of). When I enabled Google adsense in admob along with 'adult" ads, the app acted just fine and loaded those ads. If I remove ad mob from my application, the app starts up fine. It randomly will just show a blank screen and never loads any of the buttons and other times loads all buttons with the ads. Any ideas?

Here is my index activity:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView1);
        adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
        backCheck = 0;
    }
```

main.xml is just 10 buttons and the ad.... nothing fancy.
But it will just sit there and show a blank screen (it seems if it cant fetch an ad.)

The only information I have on logcat is...

```
06-02 19:45:10.923: INFO/Ads(264): To get test ads on this device, call adRequest.addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR);
06-02 19:45:11.053: WARN/Ads(264): loadAd called while the ad is already loading.
06-02 19:45:12.033: INFO/ARMAssembler(64): generated scanline__00000077:03010104_00000004_00000000 [ 22 ipp] (41 ins) at [0x451220:0x4512c4] in 2310362 ns
06-02 19:45:12.323: INFO/ActivityManager(64): Displayed activity com.robores.elect/.Index: 3500 ms (total 3500 ms)
06-02 19:45:12.453: INFO/Ads(264): adRequestUrlHtml: <html><head><script src="http://www.gstatic.com/afma/sdk-core-v40.js"></script><script>AFMA_buildAdURL({"preqs":0,"u_sd":1.5,"slotname":"a14dd7f0258a8b7","u_w":320,"msid":"com.robores.elect","simulator":1,"cap":"m,a","js":"afma-sdk-a-v4.1.0","isu":"B3EEABB8EE11C2BE770B684D95219ECB","format":"320x50_mb","net":"ed","app_name":"1.android.com.robores.elect","hl":"en","u_h":533,"u_audio":4,"u_so":"p"});</script></head><body></body></html>
06-02 19:45:14.573: INFO/Ads(264): Received ad url: <"url": "http://r.admob.com:80/ad_source.php?preqs=0&u_sd=1.5&slotname=a14dd7f0258a8b7&u_w=320&msid=com.robores.elect&cap=m%2Ca&js=afma-sdk-a-v4.1.0&isu=B3EEABB8EE11C2BE770B684D95219ECB&format=320x50_mb&net=ed&app_name=1.android.com.robores.elect&hl=en&u_h=533&u_audio=4&u_so=p&output=html&region=mobile_app&u_tz=0&ex=1&client_sdk=1", "afmaNotifyDt": "null">
06-02 19:45:16.573: WARN/webcore(264): Can't get the viewWidth after the first layout
06-02 19:45:16.693: DEBUG/dalvikvm(264): GC freed 3551 objects / 299672 bytes in 100ms
06-02 19:45:16.753: DEBUG/webviewglue(264): nativeDestroy view: 0x365538
06-02 19:45:16.763: ERROR/webcoreglue(264): The real object has been deleted
06-02 19:45:17.075: INFO/Ads(264): onReceiveAd()
```

Comment: loadAd called while the ad is already loading. just don't call loadAd , it's done automatically.

Answer (score 0):

```
AdView adView = (AdView)findById(R.id.adview1);
(new Thread() {
        public void run() {
             Looper.prepare();
             adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
        }
    }).start();
```

Put the above code in onCreate of Activity!!

Do loading of ad in separate thread not in main thread !!